# How to modify a form when returning it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, forms

I am looking to modify a form from the user and return that different form in django, however I have tried many different ways, all in views.py, including:

1. Directly modifying it by doing `str(form) += "modification"`
2. returning a new form by `newform = str(form) + "modification"`
3. creating a different Post in models, but then I realized that wouldn't work because I only want one post

All the above have generated errors such as `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`, `TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'HttpResponseRedirect'`, `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'save'`, and another authority error that said I can't modify a form or something like that.

Here is a snippet from views.py:

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['content']
    title = ['title']   #
    template_name = 'blog/post_new.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #debugging 
        tempvar = (str(form).split('required id="id_content">'))[1].split('</textarea></td>')[0]  #url
        r = requests.get(tempvar)
        tree = fromstring(r.content)
        title = tree.findtext('.//title')
        print(title)

        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        if "http://" in str(form).lower() or "https://" in str(form).lower():
            if tempvar.endswith(' '):   
                return super().form_valid(form)
            elif " http" in tempvar:   
                return super().form_valid(form)
            elif ' ' not in tempvar:
                return super().form_valid(form)
            else:
                return None
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=500, default='SOME STRING')  #

    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes= models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.content[:5], self.title[:5]) #

    @property
    def number_of_comments(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(post_connected=self).count()
```

And in home.html, where the post (along with the title and content) is supposed to be shown:

```
                    <a
                            style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) !important;"
                            href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">
                        <p class="mb-4">
                            {{ post.content }}
                            {{ post.title }}  #
                        </p>
                    </a>
```

The original template I'm modifying can be found [here](https://github.com/redianmarku/Django-Twitter-Clone).

Thank you so much for your help, I will be very glad to take any advice!!

Ps: I'm using Python 3.7.4

Comment: The `form` is a [django model forms object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), and it isn't handled as a `str`. Can you explain in your question what the _desired_ outcome would be? It's difficult to form a useful answer without it.

Comment: @damon Instead of just posting a link/content, I want to automatically get the headline of the article and also display it as a title. Unfortunately, I don't know how to add the title to the form so that it can be displayed... :(

Answer (score 0):

Create a `forms.py` file inside the app you are talking about, it should look like this:

```
from django import forms
from . import models

class YourFormName(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = models.your_model_name
    fields = ['field1', 'field2' ,...] # Here you write the fields of your model, this fields will appear on the form where user post data
```

Then you call that form into your `views.py` so Django can render it into your template, like this:

```
def your_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.YourFormName(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user= request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('template.html') # To redirect if the form is valid
    else:
        form = forms.YourFormName()
    return render(request, "template.html", {'form': form}) # The template if the form is not valid
```

And the last thing to do is create the `template.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <form action="{% url 'the_url_that_renders_this_template' %}" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

If you want to take the data from DB submitted in that form, you do so with a new function in `views.py`:

```
def show_items(request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = YourModelName.objects.all()
    context = {
        "data": data
    }
    return render(request, "show_items.html", context)
```

Then in `show_items.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

{% for item in data %}

{{item.field1}}
{{item.field2}}
...
{{The items you want to show in that template}}

{% enfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

That's what you wanted to do? If not, add a further explanation on what actually you want to do

Comment: Thank you so much!! Just to clarify, this code allows me to modify the user's input, right? (like allow me to take in the user's form input, add a dynamic text to the user's input, and display the user's input along with the added text )

Comment: What do you mean by adding dynamic text? An example may help me understand what you actually want

Comment: So you know how twitter displays the title of articles when you link them? I want to do that, where if a user submits a link as the "content", I add the title of the article with the link. I've already written the manual part of that in views.py, though, I was just wondering how to return that parsed title to the template.

Comment: I think you can call the object in the template like `{{ obj.link }}` and the with some kind of JS or even with an HTML tag you would be able to parse the link and display text based on that link, but I don't think this has to deal with Django itself

Comment: Thanks so much!! I'm not very sure how to do a JS or HTML tag though... could you please link me a few resources or edit your answer? Also are you sure it's compatible with requests (it can import modules)?